# Selecting value from table if not null (with inner join query)

Tags: mysql

I have been looking at other solutions on here for this but they seem to specify on normal queries and not joins, unless I'm missing something.

I have the following mysqli query in a function (it loads a job and all the details that go with it)

```
$sql = "
SELECT j.*
     , p.*
     , i.*
     , s.*
     , t.* 
  FROM jobs j
  JOIN job_priority p
    ON p.priority_id = j.priority_id 
  JOIN it_staff i
    ON i.staff_id = j.assigned_to  
  JOIN job_status s
    ON s.status_id = j.status_id 
  JOIN tasks t
    ON t.job_id = j.job_id 
 WHERE j.job_id = '$job_id'
";
```

Now this query works fine but only if there is a value in the tasks table assigned to the corresponding job_id, but if there isnt any tasks assigned to the job then the result will come up blank. I understand WHY this is the case but what I want to do is select all the data and return it even if there are no tasks.

I have looked at IS NOT NULL and a few other solutions but I'm not sure on the correct syntax for it when using a join query like above.

So I am seeking the syntax to only select the tasks if they exist (the tasks and jobs table are linked/joined by the job_id column).

Comment: Do you know what a LEFT JOIN does?

Comment: Vaguely, I have always used inner joins and never really used the other join methods. I take it this is where i should be looking! @LukStorms can I use a left join in combination with my inner joins all in the same query ?

Comment: you just need a left join instead of your inner join

Comment: Yes, one can use different types of joins in the same query.

Comment: @LukStorms your a diamond! Thank you very much and sorry everyone for the duplicate question !

Comment: Well this question got my account banned from asking more questions for 6 months which seems pretty harsh, I get the rules are there to keep the quality of the site but I clearly didnt find or understand any of the answers I did come across hence why I asked. Seems a bit over the top to ban me whoever did.  I will use this comment to ask one last question before i just give up on this platform all-together 

Why do people short hand their tables to single letters? is there any benefit to this as i my opinion it looks more messy/complicated? @LukStorms

Comment: It's an automated process I think, so there noone to look at with angry eyes.  But yeah, that sound harsh indeed. And I had no idea duplicate questions could also cause that.  About the short alias names, it's often more readable than using the full table names.

Comment: @LukStorms I wish you where an admin to be honest mate! thanks for your help dude.

Comment: @LukStorms Someone upvoted the question and not I can post questions again! if it was you then thank you very much! you saved my account :D

Comment: I had no idea a closure will impose a ban. A short letter comes in handy when you have a lot of fields to select and/or conditions.